# How many scrolls do I need to keep the spell Disguise Self all the time?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, character-creation, wizard

I plan to create a dragonborn wizard disguising as an elf as the society there is racist towards anyone but elves.

Constraints:

- The character is level 1.
- I can't have any feat.

As far as I know, I have two slots of level 1 spells, and the spell *disguise self* lasts for 1 hour.

If I wanted to keep my slots for other spells, **How many scrolls of Disguise self do I need if I want to keep my elf form for 30 days?**

Comment: Is this question really just asking for a simple multiplication, or is there more to it that I'm not seeing?

Comment: Is everyone else in the group playing elves? It seems odd that the DM would allow you to play a dragonborn but insist that you disguise yourself as an elf 100% of the time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you wanted to keep disguise self up for 30 days at 16 hours a day, so assuming you have a secure place to sleep, it would require 480 spell scrolls. (Adjust number of hours and recalculate if using different long rest times).

That’s a lot of scrolls.

But the bigger question is “could this even work?” *Disguise self* is a 1st level spell. In the grand scheme of things, it’s good for getting by every once in a while, **but it will not hold up to scrutiny**. Any physical inspection will reveal you are using an illusion, and any other inspection is only a DC13 (save for 1st level scroll) Investigation check to realize you are a fake.

Further, people are going to notice you whipping out spell scrolls 16 times a day. It makes you *more* conspicuous, not less. Overall your plan is unrealistic. It requires too many scrolls, too much maintenance, and the illusion isn’t really that good - you will be discovered eventually.

If you aren’t committed entirely to the Wizard class and want to save the rainforest from Big Corporate Paper Corporation, with two levels of warlock, you get access to the Eldritch invocation Mask of Many Faces:

> You can cast *disguise self* at will, without expending a spell slot.

This solves your paper supply issue entirely, but the shortcomings of *disguise self* still apply.

Comment: Also using the sane magic item price list which I use the 480 scrolls would cost 48000 gold pieces!

Comment: There's also the hat of disguise (DMG, p.173), which does the same thing as the invocation while you're wearing it. A DM might let you have that if it fits the character concept

Comment: In Pathfinder (and probably in DnD 3.5 that Pathfinder was based on), the hat of disguise was one of the cheapest magic items, enough so that it was reasonable to give a starting character with maybe a debt or a favor owed they could pay off by third level or so at most.

Comment: In the sane magic item guide the hat of disguise is 5000gp, more than a +2 sword, and it has huge use across every level. I am not sure it is really fair to give this kind of item to one player when other people might have to multiclass in order to achieve their concepts. It opens up all sorts of potential for jealousy, not least if there is a warlock in the group!

Comment: @SeriousBri Making one player start as an extreme social outcast isn't exactly fair either.

Comment: @mark wells It is that players choice, and the DM who made a racist world. There are better solutions than powerful magic items.

Comment: @SeriousBri While the *Hat of Disguise* is certainly useful *sometimes*, I wouldn't exactly call it "powerful". Outside of this characters particular circumstance, the ability to cast a level 1 utility spell (and a rather niche one at that) *ad nauseam* is rather unhelpful. If it allowed them to cast *Knock* at will, then *that* could probably be considered powerful. And in this particular characters circumstance, it doesn't really add any more power, but it certainly could (and probably will) add more tension and drama, which seems like a plus.

Comment: @OP you may also want to consider the fact that you can't cast while sleeping, so you're going to have to take into account hiding during your long rests.

Comment: @revenantbacon hat of disguise can transform a players options, that's pretty powerful in my eyes and a significant selling point of the warlock as a class. It's no artifact, but has a huge impact in the right campaign. All I know is that I would be pretty jealous and pretty close to demanding a similar item for whatever character I created.

Comment: @SeriousBri That's the main thing, it's powerful *in very specific circumstances*, like say, political intrigue, but even in instances where it's strong, it's still not that strong. And from what we've been told about the campaign from OP, I don't think there's going to be much opportunity to abuse it. As for expecting power parity among the players, yes, I totally agree. Shouldn't give out special swag to only one player just because of a weird backstory that they thought up, everyone should get something, or no one should.